# UIDatePicker with .compact style doesn't respect content hugging priority

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uidatepicker

I think that the new `UIDatePicker` (iOS 14+) with the `.compact` style doesn't work correctly with AutoLayout.

Making a simple layout with a `UILabel` and `UIDatePicker` where the `UIDatePicker` has higher content-hugging priority should result in a layout where the `UILabel` is being stretched if there is too much space available but that's not what happens.

That's the result that I get:

[image: UIDatePicker is stretched but it shouldn't be]

Here is sample code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Label"
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return label
    }()
    
    private let datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
        return datePicker
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(datePicker)
        
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        datePicker.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow + 1, for: .horizontal)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePicker.bottomAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePicker.leadingAnchor, constant: -8),
            
            datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            datePicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this a known issue?

Comment: You are assuming that the date picker has an intrinsic content size width based on its text, like a label. But why should we expect that?

Comment: @matt, I expect this because of this like in Apple's documentation
`You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout. Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their intrinsic content size.`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker

Comment: OK, thanks. I experimented and for me this works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Set the label's horizontal content hugging priority to `.defaultLow-1`.

[image]

Comment: This works but I still think it's a strange behavior/bug. Setting `.defaultLow + 1` to the `UIDatePicker` should have the same effect in this example.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I'll look at it some more.

Comment: OK I'm with you. It looks like something comes along and sets the date picker's content hugging priority back to `.defaultLow` and that's why you have to mess with the label instead. So what I did is a workaround but that's all it is. You might want to file a bug report on this.

Comment: The value doesn't actually not change but it _acts_ like the value is still 250.